# Do you need to know special relativity in order to learn quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, education

I just started my special relativity class and I want to study quantum mechanics but I don’t want spoilers to the rest of my special relativity class, also if it’s required I won’t understand the material in quantum mechanics. Should I worry about this problems? I only want to learn quantum mechanics in a first class depth

Comment: QM and special relativity are independent subjects. If you want to learn Quantum Field Theory (QFT), on the other hand, which is way more complicated than QM, you will need a strong foundation in both QM and special relativity.

Comment: Typically a course on QM will consider some small relativistic corrections (say, to hydrogenic energy levels) using perturbation theory. This should not spoil SR for you. You should study both simultaneously.

Comment: If you want depth on QM, you need Galilean Relativity. You need special relativity at a medium level, to start QFT, which is the QM of systems with an infinite number of DoF.

Answer (score 1):

For the usual introductory topics in Special Relativity and Quantum Mechanics, they can be learned independently.

One might need a little special relativity when dealing with the deBroglie hypothesis, but one can probably get by with just accepting the hypothesis without a more thorough background of the motivation.

Comment: You can easily motivate De Broglie's hypothesis by bringing experiments by Davisson and Germer and comparing them with von Laue's. No need for SR.